# Trigger a auto-response to Android Studio From Laravel Backend

Tags: android, laravel, interrupt

This question may be a bit silly. So please bear with me.

I have an `Android Studio` application with `Laravel` as the backend, and `MySQL` as database. There are two modules: `user` and `rider`. Whenever a user gives an order, it is stored in the database. Now the rider is making a `volley` request at each `20` seconds interval to check if there is any order available in the database in his/her preferred area. If there are any available user order, the rider is prompted a message, otherwise the rider hangs in a tight loop waiting for an order.

But I want to do this work in a manner such that whenever there is a new order in the database, a message will be sent to a rider from the server automatically and thus the rider doesn't have to poll to check if there is new order. How can I do this in a way that involves interrupt?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, what you're looking for is called "push notifications". Look it up, you'll find plenty of resources online on how to set them up

Answer (score 1):

Use [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to send push notification with data. You can use [Laravel-FCM](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM) package to send push from your backend Laravel application.

Answer (score 0):

you need push notification services

Laravel Document: [Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting)

and there are free services to push like [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/)